# How to format the Available Value label field in Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2010

I've looked at several similar Q&As but nothing quite matched what I'm after (unless I misunderstood!).

I have written a query with a parameter requiring the week number, but I have the dropdown for the selection display the week start date to make it more user friendly. I did this using the Label field, under Available Values in the Report Parameter Properties dialog box.

[So, main query report is based on has this code line `WHERE (REG_Session_No IN (@WeekNo))`.
 Report Data pane/Parameters shows @WeekNo which is Text, and Available Values are taken from a query called qWeekDateSelection.....

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(REG_Session_Date) AS WeekStartDate, REG_Session_No
FROM            REGStud
INNER JOIN      REGSessn ON REGStud.REGStud_key = REGSessn.REGSessn_key
GROUP BY REGSessn.REG_Session_No, REGStud.Year
HAVING   (MIN(REGSessn.REG_Session_Date) < GETDATE() - 1) 
   AND   (REGStud.Year = CASE WHEN Month(GetDate()) < 8 THEN Year(GetDate()) - 1 ELSE Year(GetDate()) END)
ORDER BY WeekStartDate DESC
```

...Value field is REG_Session_No and Label field is WeekStartDate.]

Now, the dropdown is displayed as dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss (e.g. 06/01/2014 00:00:00).

** I would like to get rid of the hh:mm:ss part **

One way to do this is to do a cast in the underlying query, i.e. `SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MIN(REGSessn.REG_Session_Date) AS varchar(12)) AS WeekStartDate`.

The dropdown then displays MMM dd yyyy (e.g. Sep 30 2013).

> > > > My Question, though, is can this be formatted in Reporting Services itself rather in the query?

I then might be able to do more elegant formatting, perhaps. I am new to SSRS and know of "Parameters!" but don't know how or where to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a copy of SSRS on my current machine, so I am going off memory here. If you make it a text box instead of a drop down, you can make it a datetime field (under properties?)

In the default value of that field you can put a formula to select the first day of the current week.

I shall try and find a code sample for you.

Here, this should be what you are looking for.

```
=DATEADD("d", 1 - DATEPART(DateInterval.WeekDay, Today(),FirstDayOfWeek.Monday), Today())
```

The sample is taken from here.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic953520-150-1.aspx#bm953561

Comment: Thanks for that, though it perhaps highlights my lack of knowledge thus far! The dropdown is created automatically by SSRS in Preview or when I deploy the report, but it is not in the Design tab so not sure how I should proceed....?

Comment: You can drop and drag from your toolbox. Not sure where your toolbox is?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnD1-mAKSz4

Just after the 5 min point it uses the tool box.

Hopefully that is your version of VS.

Comment: Useful tutorials on YouTube, thanks for that link. Similarly, on http://youtu.be/6Wzz8c3AWPU, at about 11:05 you will see an example of what I am doing with the Value field and Label field.

Comment: I am getting the values from a query. You can see it creates the dropdown automatically for these parameters, so I'm not sure adding a textbox is much use....or do you mean I should use the textbox.value as a pseudo parameter and filter the query on that instead? 
I was hoping there would be an elegant solution of being able to format how the Label field is displayed but perhaps there isn't. [Btw, I'm using Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: In the video you linked too, from approximately 11:55-12:25. You should be able to use the code I provided after pressing the Fx button.

Alternatively, you could fill your parameter from the textbox. That is what I usually have done in the past.

Comment: Didn't want to just ignore your help, so thank you very much for the guidance. I think the answer to the nub of my question is it can't be done. As to finding work arounds, this might help get there but is more work than needed (at the moment!). Cheers.